# Issue with Substring returning 1 less than specified length in VB

Tags: vb.net

The VB code is used to read in complex barcodes and separate their AIs. This block of code correctly processes the complex barcode 01984000000726283102002046102577855921221505 and makes it through the ElseIf correctly:

```
ElseIf (ScannedBarcode.Length >= 44 AndAlso (ScannedBarcode.Substring(0, 2) = "01" _
                                       And ScannedBarcode.Substring(16, 4) = "3102" _
                                       And ScannedBarcode.Substring(26, 2) = "10" _
                                       And ScannedBarcode.Substring(36, 2) = "21")) Then
                oProduct.ProductCode = ScannedBarcode.Substring(2, 14)
                oProduct.ExpiryDate = "" 'Expiry date
                oProduct.Qty = ScannedBarcode.Substring(20, 6) / 100
```

However, when the same approach is used to process a different complex barcode, 0195391509285882108054057171710133102001202, with differently arranged AIs, the substring seems to be returning 1 less than the specified length, e.g. 310 instead of 3102.

```
ElseIf ScannedBarcode.Length >= 44 AndAlso (ScannedBarcode.Substring(0, 2) = "01" _
                             And ScannedBarcode.Substring(16, 2) = "10" _
                             And ScannedBarcode.Substring(26, 2) = "17" _
                             And ScannedBarcode.Substring(35, 4) = "3102") Then
                oProduct.ProductCode = ScannedBarcode.Substring(2, 14)
                oProduct.ExpiryDate = ScannedBarcode.Substring(27, 6) 'Expiry date
                oProduct.Qty = ScannedBarcode.Substring(38, 6) / 100
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I've removed the `vba` tag - please note that vb.net <> vba

Comment: Can you please post a more complete code sample, i.e. including the If / EndIf, a variable/constant defining the barcode, and some debug/log output in the respective branches. However do recognise that ScannedBarcode.Length >= 44 should evaluate to false as the length of the barcode given is 43.

Comment: A typical case of SubString() seemingly returning fewer characters than asked for, and using 44 instead of 43, is the string containing a non-printing Unicode codepoint.  Use the ToCharArray() method in the debugger to see them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your second barcode is only 43 characters and not 44. And perhaps because of that, one of your `SubString`s doesn't match:

```
ScannedBarcode.Substring(26, 2)
```

It returns `71` and not the `17` you expected.